# Is there a way I could assign 2 separate functions on 2 onclick in a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, button

I wanted to:
play the animation on my first click and
stop it on my second click of the same button.
Thanks.

Comment: The key is in closures, wrap a function in an iffy that contains a "running" boolean state local variable, which your function uses to determine if it stops or runs with a simple if/then/else

Comment: That's not the scope of SO, but... You will have to save the "state" anywhere so you can check it in the click handler.

Comment: onclick toggle two functions, one for animate one for stop animation.

Comment: @InterviewSortout how do I tell the button to toggle on off?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do like this

```js
function performAction(event){
  
  var button = event.currentTarget;
  var action = button.innerHTML;

  if(action == "Play"){
  
     button.innerHTML = "Stop"
    //play animation
    
   
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = "Play"
    //stop animation
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button  onclick="performAction(event)" >Play</button>
</div>
```

Comment: While this undoubtedly works, it is relaying on external factors which is something you do not want to do, check my answer below for a more "good practice" approach.

Comment: @Dellirium - Your solution is nice , But this guy needs  a simpler solution

Comment: Someone was pissed I guess, idk, mine got - as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution using closures, you should learn more on how [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) work.

```js
function generateMyStatefullFunction(){
  var someState = false;
  
  return function theActualFunctionThatDoesThings(){
    if (someState){
      console.log("State will be set to false, next click wont trigger this message");
    }
    someState = !someState;
  }
}

var onClickHandler = generateMyStatefullFunction();

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
```

```html
<button id="button"> Fire every second click</button>
```

Comment: I seriously have no clue what closures are but thankks!

Comment: I've no clue why someone downvoted me, so I am as baffled as you are... Find more about closures here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work they are a really important concept in javascript